# StringVar.get() returns an empty string in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create an app using `tkinter`, and this snippet of code shows one of the frames where the user can select a value from a dropdown menu, and the selected value would be printed on the terminal.

```
class Frame(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.var = StringVar()

    
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(
            self,
            textvariable=self.var,
            postcommand=self.update_list_combobox,
            state="readonly",
        )
        self.combobox.pack()
        print(self.var.get())
    

    def update_list_combobox(self):
        _list = self.controller.data.columns.tolist()
        self.combobox["values"] = _list
```

When I run this code, I see an empty string printed on the screen. I tried printing the value of `self.combobox.get()`, I see an empty string again. The selection I make from the UI is not being captured by the `StringVar` nor the `combobox` object. Any help to figure out why that's the case will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You run `print(self.var.get())` just after you create the `StringVar()`, so there hasn't been any time for it's value to change from the default: `""`.

Comment: Can you suggest how I should change the code so that I can get the value of `self.var.get())` after the user selects a value from the dropdown menu?

Comment: Look at `<tkinter.StringVar>.trace` and look at examples of `ttk.Combobox`.

Comment: Take a look at event driven programming too

Answer (score 0):

I went through the `tkiner` documentation, and figured out the correct way to  get the selected dropdown value. The trick was to bind a combobox click to a function from where the selected value can be retreived. Here is the modified snippet of code :-

```
class Frame(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.var = StringVar()

    
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(
            self,
            textvariable=self.var,
            postcommand=self.update_list_combobox,
            state="readonly",
        )
        self.combobox.pack()
        print(self.var.get())
        self.combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.get_values)

    def update_list_combobox(self):
        _list = self.controller.data.columns.tolist()
        self.combobox["values"] = _list

    def get_values(self, *args):
        print(self.combobox.get())
```